# Restriction of generic is not sufficient for type

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I have the following abstract base class

```
export abstract class ThemeService<T extends ITypedTemplate>{
    private personalThemesSubject: BehaviorSubject<T[]> = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);

    private fetchPersonalThemes(): void {
       this.personalThemesService.readTemplates()
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
          .subscribe(personalThemes => this.personalThemesSubject.next(personalThemes)); // Error
  }
      // .... more code 
}
```

Here `personalThemesService` is defined by the following interface

```
export interface ITemplateService {
    readTemplates(): Observable<ITypedTemplate[]>; 
}
```

Why do I get an error when updating the `personalThemesSubject` with `next`? In the definition of the class I let `T` extend from the same type which `readTemplates` is returning

*Argument of type 'ITypedTemplate[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T[]'.
Type 'ITypedTemplate' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'ITypedTemplate' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ITypedTemplate'*

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. Right now this is a snippet of some larger code base and there are lots of errors about missing types and values, so it's very difficult to begin to inspect what's going on.